# Verification of my Update statement

Tags: postgresql, servlets, jdbc

I want to know if this statement is correct, because when i run it no changes made.

**here's the code :**

```
   String name= request.getParameter("eid");
   String newname = request.getParameter("categoryName");
   String newimage = request.getParameter("ImagePath");

   File imgfile = new File(newimage);
   FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imgfile);

   PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement
   ("Update category set category_name=?, category_image = ? where category_name =?");
   pre.setString(1, newname);
   pre.setBinaryStream(2,fin,(int)imgfile.length());
   pre.setString(3, name);
   pre.executeUpdate();  

   pre.close();
   conn.close();
   }

   catch (Exception e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: what kind of error you getting.. if dont mine paste the stacetrace

Comment: No error, but the operation update does not work :/

Comment: did you see the console side..

Comment: yes, i see it and there's no a problem

Comment: what did mean `fin` like  `pre.setBinaryStream(2,fin,(int)imgfile.length());`

Comment: give me full code for my mail_id or paste here...

Comment: pre.setBinaryStream(2,fin,(int)imgfile.length()); to insert image in my database

Comment: what is name of using in db, and if you can paste your code here

Comment: You've not called `commit()` on your connection.

Comment: @jmail:I can't post my code here

Comment: where should i called commit() ?

Comment: I use commit() but also the operation doesn't work

Comment: when i put System.out.println(pre); after pre.setString(3,name); 
the result is as follows :
Update category set category_name='iphone' , category_image = ? where category_name =NULL

Comment: @Sarra show the table details like column names.

Comment: The problem was in my jsp page